# I want to SUM every row after the first

Tags: excel

I want to SUM every row after the first
An example of what I want is

```
=sum(A:A) (but after the first cell)
```

It causes a circular logic with that though ..

Comment: whats the problem with sum(A2:A99999) ?

Comment: While you can certainly program in Excel, it needs VBA, hence this question (about a particular cell formula) is not really suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's ..

```
=sum(a2:a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=sum(a:a) - a1
```

or

```
=sum(a2:a65536)
```

- note: 65,536 is the row limit for excel 2003, 1,048,576 for 2010 -- check your version to be sure

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 both answers above give me an error if I put the formulas below in cell A1:

```
=SUM(A:A) - A1 //This gives a circular error
```

and

```
=SUM(A1:A) //This gives a #NAME? error
```

Instead, I like to do the following:

- In a field in the row that I want to skip(i.e. A1), enter text that uniquely describes the row as the header/skip row (i.e. 'header-skip')
- In the column that I want to sum (i.e. B:B) without a circular reference, enter a "SUMIF" formula using the header text as part of the IF to skip.  =SUMIF(A:A, "<>header-skip", B:B)

For example

```
[   ][      A      ][                 B                 ]
[ 1 ][ header-skip ][ =SUMIF(A:A, "<>header-skip", B:B) ]
[ 2 ][             ][                9.5                ]
[ 3 ][             ][                7.5                ]
[ 4 ][             ][               25.0                ]
```

Your Formula on line 1 should now correctly show "42" without any circular reference.  This is easier for me to remember and faster for me to put in a sheet than using offsets, indexes, and indirects, etc.

Hope this helps someone!